# In JavaScript Why should I use encodeURI/encodeURIComponent?

Tags: javascript, urlencode

I know they 2 will encode a URL before sending to server, but what's the reason for doing so.

I've never used the encode function before in my porject and everything goes well.

So I'm curious in what situation we need to use them, and if not what problem will rise.

Comment: How about a URL with special characters? Did you try without encoding the URL ?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245333/should-encodeuri-ever-be-used

Answer (score 5):

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/save-dudes-long-message?message=Hi mom! This message will break this URL request, won't it? Question marks and things like that don't fly!! #@#$!
```

Certain characters, such as "?" or "&" or "#", are reserved for browser URLs. If you don't escape them, the browser/server will misinterpret your request and send something else.

Encoding it will convert those characters so that they aren't interpreted literally until they are de-encoded at the server side.

Comment: why not just use encodeURIComponent instead on just the message part?
so like:
var msg = "Hi mom! This message will break this URL request, won't it? Question marks and things like that don't fly!! #@#$!";
var url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/save-dudes-long-message?message='+ encodeURIComponent(msg) ;